# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V

Tags: java, maven, gwt, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium test in maven project.This project is GWT Web application.There are GWT dependencies,hibernate dependencies in pom.xml.I have created a new class in test package to run the selenium test case.I have also included selenium server-2.33.0 dependencies in pom.xml but getting following exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
```

Also getting exception for chrome driver.Please guide me how to solve this issue.

I am using following dependencies in pom.xml:-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SeleniumDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumDemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
            <version>4.7</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guiceberry</groupId>
            <artifactId>guiceberry</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assisted-inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mvp4g</groupId>
            <artifactId>mvp4g</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gwt-maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maps</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2b.gwt22</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gwt-html5-geolocation</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-html5-geolocation</artifactId>
            <version>gwt-html5-geolocation</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtupload</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-misc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gwt-servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.carrotsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-benchmarks</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.170</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for Encryption/Decryption -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwt.crypto</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.infomas</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotation-detector</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mail dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

After running mvn dependency:tree command,I got the output as follows:

```
root@dhananjay:~# cd /root/helios/workspace/SeleniumDemo
root@dhananjay:~/helios/workspace/SeleniumDemo# mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GWT Maven Archetype
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-beta-2/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.pom
680b downloaded  (wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon/1.0-beta-2/wagon-1.0-beta-2.pom
5K downloaded  (wagon-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/4/maven-parent-4.pom
9K downloaded  (maven-parent-4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/1.0-beta-2/wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.pom
637b downloaded  (wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-providers/1.0-beta-2/wagon-providers-1.0-beta-2.pom
1K downloaded  (wagon-providers-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav/1.0-beta-2/wagon-webdav-1.0-beta-2.pom
1K downloaded  (wagon-webdav-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/slide/slide-webdavlib/2.1/slide-webdavlib-2.1.pom
648b downloaded  (slide-webdavlib-2.1.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/2.0.2/commons-httpclient-2.0.2.pom
6K downloaded  (commons-httpclient-2.0.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/de/zeigermann/xml/xml-im-exporter/1.1/xml-im-exporter-1.1.pom
248b downloaded  (xml-im-exporter-1.1.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/1.0-beta-2/wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.pom
1K downloaded  (wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-2/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.pom
845b downloaded  (wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.pom
1K downloaded  (jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.pom
1K downloaded  (doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-1.0-alpha-10.pom
8K downloaded  (doxia-1.0-alpha-10.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/6/maven-parent-6.pom
19K downloaded  (maven-parent-6.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-external/1.0-beta-2/wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.pom
1K downloaded  (wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh-common/1.0-beta-2/wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.pom
851b downloaded  (wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom
1K downloaded  (plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0.2/plexus-containers-1.0.2.pom
471b downloaded  (plexus-containers-1.0.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/plexus/plexus-root/1.0.3/plexus-root-1.0.3.pom
5K downloaded  (plexus-root-1.0.3.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.2/plexus-utils-1.0.2.pom
740b downloaded  (plexus-utils-1.0.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-ssh/1.0-beta-2/wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.pom
1K downloaded  (wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.27/jsch-0.1.27.pom
965b downloaded  (jsch-0.1.27.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.6/plexus-utils-1.4.6.pom
2K downloaded  (plexus-utils-1.4.6.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.pom
2K downloaded  (file-management-1.1.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/4/maven-shared-components-4.pom
2K downloaded  (maven-shared-components-4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.0/maven-shared-io-1.0.pom
2K downloaded  (maven-shared-io-1.0.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.2/maven-artifact-2.0.2.pom
765b downloaded  (maven-artifact-2.0.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.2/maven-2.0.2.pom
12K downloaded  (maven-2.0.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.2/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.2.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-artifact-manager-2.0.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.pom
588b downloaded  (wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-1.0-alpha-6.pom
6K downloaded  (wagon-1.0-alpha-6.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.2/plexus-utils-1.2.pom
767b downloaded  (plexus-utils-1.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.5/plexus-1.0.5.pom
5K downloaded  (plexus-1.0.5.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/1.1/maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.pom
4K downloaded  (maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0.pom
360b downloaded  (asm-3.0.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/asm/asm-parent/3.0/asm-parent-3.0.pom
2K downloaded  (asm-parent-3.0.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.5/maven-project-2.0.5.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-project-2.0.5.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.5/maven-2.0.5.pom
5K downloaded  (maven-2.0.5.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.5/maven-model-2.0.5.pom
2K downloaded  (maven-model-2.0.5.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.5/maven-artifact-2.0.5.pom
727b downloaded  (maven-artifact-2.0.5.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.pom
3K downloaded  (maven-dependency-tree-1.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/9/maven-shared-components-9.pom
3K downloaded  (maven-shared-components-9.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.8/maven-project-2.0.8.pom
2K downloaded  (maven-project-2.0.8.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.8/maven-2.0.8.pom
11K downloaded  (maven-2.0.8.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.0.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-common-artifact-filters-1.0.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/8/maven-shared-components-8.pom
2K downloaded  (maven-shared-components-8.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.8/maven-artifact-2.0.8.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-artifact-2.0.8.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-plugin-testing-harness/1.1/maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.pom
6K downloaded  (maven-plugin-testing-harness-1.1.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-components/7/maven-shared-components-7.pom
2K downloaded  (maven-shared-components-7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0/maven-project-2.0.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-project-2.0.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0/maven-core-2.0.pom
5K downloaded  (maven-core-2.0.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.2/plexus-utils-1.4.2.pom
1K downloaded  (plexus-utils-1.4.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.pom
1K downloaded  (plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting/2.0.4/maven-reporting-2.0.4.pom
700b downloaded  (maven-reporting-2.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.4/maven-2.0.4.pom
11K downloaded  (maven-2.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.4/maven-project-2.0.4.pom
1K downloaded  (maven-project-2.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.pom
1K downloaded  (doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/oro/oro/2.0.7/oro-2.0.7.pom
141b downloaded  (oro-2.0.7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.4/maven-plugin-api-2.0.4.pom
643b downloaded  (maven-plugin-api-2.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.4/maven-reporting-api-2.0.4.pom
902b downloaded  (maven-reporting-api-2.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-7.pom
1K downloaded  (doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-6/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.pom
771b downloaded  (plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-6.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.4/plexus-components-1.1.4.pom
2K downloaded  (plexus-components-1.1.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.2/plexus-velocity-1.1.2.pom
7K downloaded  (plexus-velocity-1.1.2.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.0.4/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.pom
168b downloaded  (commons-logging-api-1.0.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/velocity/velocity/1.4/velocity-1.4.pom
2K downloaded  (velocity-1.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/velocity/velocity-dep/1.4/velocity-dep-1.4.pom
1K downloaded  (velocity-dep-1.4.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-7.pom
1K downloaded  (doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-7.pom)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/oro/oro/2.0.7/oro-2.0.7.jar
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-7.jar
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.jar
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.jar
63K downloaded  (oro-2.0.7.jar)
30K downloaded  (file-management-1.1.jar)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.0.4/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
13K downloaded  (maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.jar)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/velocity/velocity/1.4/velocity-1.4.jar
25K downloaded  (commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/asm/asm/3.0/asm-3.0.jar
156K downloaded  (plexus-utils-1.0.2.jar)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.jar
41K downloaded  (asm-3.0.jar)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:7080/artifactory/repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.0/maven-shared-io-1.0.jar
26K downloaded  (maven-dependency-analyzer-1.1.jar)
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] SeleniumDemo:SeleniumDemo:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.4.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.9:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:test
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-android-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-iphone-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webbitserver:webbit:jar:0.4.14:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.18:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guiceberry:guiceberry:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava-testlib:jar:10.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava-gwt:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assisted-inject:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.mvp4g:mvp4g:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.gwt.inject:gin:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:3.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] +- gwt-maps:gwt-maps:jar:3.0.2b.gwt22:compile
[INFO] +- gwt-html5-geolocation:gwt-html5-geolocation:jar:gwt-html5-geolocation:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.gwtupload:gwtupload:jar:0.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.restfb:restfb:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] +- gwt-servlet:deps:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.carrotsearch:junit-benchmarks:jar:0.4.0:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.170:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.1.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.gwt.crypto:gwt-crypto:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-gwt-server:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-gwt-common:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-compat-jbossweb:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-compat-tomcat:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-compat-tomcat7:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.atmosphere:atmosphere-gwt-client:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- eu.infomas:annotation-detector:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 2):

A NoSuchMethodError indicates that classes available at runtime are different to those used to compile your code.

It usually boils down to having multiple versions of the same class on the classpath. Double check this for the class in question and remove the unwanted version.

**[EDIT]**
Add this to your pom.xml to control the version of httpclient:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>[4.2.1]</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks JamesB.I am using only one version                          **<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.33.0</version>
</dependency>**.But facing same issue.

Comment: But you mention other dependencies in your pom file. One of them must be pulling in another version of SchemeSocketFactory. Use the command mvn dependency:tree to find out which jar it is. Can you also add your pom file to your original post?

Comment: @dhananjay So it looks like that version of selenium uses version 4.2.1 of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient which contains your troublesome org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory class. Look for another jar which will be pulling in a different (probably earlier) version of the httpclient jar and exclude this transitive dependency.

Comment: Thanks JamesB.I have added my pom.xml to my post.In my repository by-default it is taking version 4.2.1 & 4.2.3 of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient under org/apache/ folder.How to exclude this transitive dependency.

Comment: @dhananjay Assuming you need to use selenium version 2.33.0, I would look to remove httpclient version 4.2.3. Can you run mvn dependency:tree from the root of your maven project and post the output?

Comment: Hi JamesB,In my post I have posted the output after running mvn dependency:tree command,please have a look.Please guide me.

Comment: I have same error as OP. Maven shows older version used in a jar 1 layer down. Adding your dependency didn't work (but v4.5.1).  Please update.
| +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.3:compile ..... +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.1:compile |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the order in the java build path in my IDE. The selenium libraries were building at the end, and I solved it put them at top of the list.

I hope it helps.

Regards