# JUnit - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)

Tags: java, spring, apache, junit, gradlew

I have been struggling with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)` while running Junit test cases in local environment. But the same test cases are running successfully in Team City build server. So far, I am skipping test cases in local development environment with

```
$ ./gradlew build -x test
```

### Configuration

As [Stackoverflow post on the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16912105/432903) suggests

```
A NoSuchMethodError indicates that classes available at runtime are different to those used to compile your code.
```

My current httpclient dependency for the module is :

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.3'
compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
```

The dependency tree(minimized) is :

```
./gradlew -q dependencies eccount-module:dependencies
+--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.2.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |         +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.5
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.1.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.7.0
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:3.1.0.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0
+--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.2.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:1.4.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.6.5
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.1
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.6.5
|    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.12
+--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:1.9.3
+--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:1.9.3
|    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:1.9.3
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.4
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4 -> 1.6
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.3
|    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.4
+--- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.2 -> 1.6
+--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
+--- commons-net:commons-net:3.1
+--- commons-io:commons-io:1.4
+--- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:20030825.184428
+--- commons-pool:commons-pool:20030825.183949
+--- org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4 -> 2.5
+--- javax.mail:mail:1.4.4
|    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.0.0.GA
|    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.6 -> 1.6.5
|    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1
|    |    +--- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2
|    |    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
|    \--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.3
|         \--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1 (*)
|    +--- cglib:cglib:2.2
|    |    \--- asm:asm:3.1
|    +--- javassist:javassist:3.12.0.GA
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.6.5
+--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.0.Final -> 1.0.1.Final
+--- hsqldb:hsqldb:1.8.0.10
+--- c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2
+--- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha:2.0-alpha-1
|    +--- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha-api:2.0-alpha-1
|    +--- com.jhlabs:filters:2.0.235
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.6 -> 1.6.5
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.6
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.6
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.5
+--- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.0.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:2.0.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.0.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- com.sun.xml.wsit:xws-security:1.3.1
|    +--- com.sun.xml.wsit:wsit-rt:1.1
|    +--- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.5.8 -> 1.6.4
|    |    +--- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.4.6
|    |    \--- org.opensaml:opensaml:2.5.1-1
|    |         \--- org.opensaml:openws:1.4.2-1
|    |              \--- org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.3.2-1
|    |                   +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.6.5
|    |                   +--- joda-time:joda-time:1.6.2
|    |                   \--- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.4.4 -> 1.4.6
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.0.7.RELEASE -> 3.1.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:2.0.3.RELEASE (*)
+--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
+--- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.6.4 (*)
+--- com.sun.xml.ws:webservices-rt:2.0.1
|    \--- javax.xml:webservices-api:2.0.1
|         \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
+--- xml-security:xmlsec:1.3.0
+--- xfire:opensaml:1.0.1
+--- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.0.1
|    +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0 -> 1.8.3
|    +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:2.1 -> 3.2.1
|    +--- commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1
|    |    \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3
|    +--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js1 -> 2.1.7
|    |    +--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|    |    +--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    |    \--- bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:138
|    |         \--- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:1.38
|    |              +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
|    |              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.38
|    |                   \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.9
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5 -> 1.6
+--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7 (*)
+--- net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:1.41.0
|    \--- org.jrobin:jrobin:1.5.9
+--- junit:junit:4.8.2
+--- org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.2.RELEASE
+--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.0
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
|    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.0
```

### The almighty stacktrace while running junit test case is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eccountJob' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/api-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'eccountRequestManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eccountRequestManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'eccountRestTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eccountRestTemplate' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' of type [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eccountRequestManager' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'eccountRestTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eccountRestTemplate' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' of type [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eccountRestTemplate' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' of type [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#2431b9' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/rest-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.<init>(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Framework are you using? (I couldn't see that in your dependency list.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Spring version is `3.1.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Okay - I can't check right now which version of httpcore that uses, but that's the next thing I'd check if I were you. It's also slightly worrying that you've got commons-httpclient as well as httpcomponent. Do you definitely need both of those?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I seem to have used both libraries, so am checking if `httpcomponent` can only be used. I also have updated the dependency tree. Thank you

Comment: Apparently, the issue was with using `GWT` which include some other version of `httpclient` module in `gwt-dev` package.

Had to exclude `httpclient` from `gwt-dev`.