# Amazon MWS implementation in android studio

Tags: amazon-mws

I am developing an application which uses MWS (Amazon market web services). What I have done import java libraries given by Amazon Configuration application with respect seller or Merchant credential. But when I run application the following error occur at run time. I put my best to get rid off but never find any helpful answer.

**AndroidRuntime:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.aun.sample java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method (Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar) org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:47) org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:93) com.example.aun.sample.MwsConnection1.getConnectionManager(MwsConnection1.java:260) com.example.aun.sample.MwsConnection1.freeze(MwsConnection1.java:227) com.example.aun.sample.MwsConnection1.newCall(MwsConnection1.java com.example.aun.sample.MwsConnection1.call(MwsConnection1.java:398) com.example.aun.sample.MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient1.getServiceStatus(MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient1.java:168) com.example.aun.sample.GetServiceStatus.invokeGetServiceStatus(GetServiceStatus.java:22) com.example.aun.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:14 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteIni) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit)

Answer (score 0):

Your log is missing the name of the missing method. I'm guessing it is "init", but anyways, it seems your build process is broken.

See this almost identical error: [NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911833/nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-http-conn-scheme-scheme-initljava-lang-stringi)